# Android App stops after savedInstanceState is implemented

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onrestoreinstancestate, onsaveinstancestate

EDIT: After adding `onPause()` and `onResume()`, the app no longer crashes; however, the instance is still not saving, and I lose the text I put inside the `EditText`. I speculate that I'm supposed to save the instance using `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and recall it using `onResume()` (or maybe using this **and** `onSaveInstanceState(), onRestoreInstanceState()` together) - I'm reading up on how to use these three methods now, and I would appreciate any pointers.

I'm currently writing a simple Android App with only a four (maybe five) activities. The app's function is to provide help and advice to students in university, where they are required to add the courses themselves (which appear on the `activity_main_page` page as buttons) - when the button is pressed, it will take the student to the advice page.

What I'm currently working on is the course adding page: `activity_add_course`. I'm trying to add a way to save the state of the `EditText`'s text (this is where the user adds the course name) when the activity is paused/stopped (for example when user presses the back button or home button), and to have it recalled when the user returns to the page.

**The app worked fine (using dummy intents to connect activities - I havent added an SQL database to actually make the app work) before I tried adding instance state saving to the App. Now that I have added instance state saving and recalling, the app stops running when I click the back button and I have no idea why? or how to fix it?** - This issue has been solved. Thanks @peresisUser

This is the code for the back button

```
btBk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent New = new Intent(AddCourse.this, MainPage.class);
                startActivity(New);
            }
        });
    }
```

And these are the codes I use for instance save and restore.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //Save instance state
        savedInstanceState.putString("edC1", edCourse1.getText()+"");
        savedInstanceState.putString("edC2", edCourse2.getText()+"");
        savedInstanceState.putString("edC3", edCourse3.getText()+"");
        savedInstanceState.putString("edC4", edCourse4.getText()+"");


    }
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //Restore instance state
        String edC1 = savedInstanceState.getString("edC1");
        edCourse1.setText(edC1+"");
        String edC2 = savedInstanceState.getString("edC2");
        edCourse2.setText(edC2+"");
        String edC3 = savedInstanceState.getString("edC3");
        edCourse3.setText(edC3+"");
        String edC4 = savedInstanceState.getString("edC4");
        edCourse4.setText(edC4+"");

    }
```

`edCourse1-4` are all different `EditTexts`.

From my understanding, the `onSaveInstanceState()` will save `edC1` as the text from `edCourse1.getText()+""` and so on, then the `onRestoreInstanceState()` will restore the `String` inside `edC1` to `edCourse1` and so on.

Having trouble on this, I have no idea how I would solve my next issue, which has to save the state of buttons on the page `activity_main_page`. Here I would have 10 buttons which start off as invisible and nameless, where `activity_add_course` will add a name to the button and make it visible. I speculate that the issue I will run into is: that all the buttons would become invisible when the app is restarted.

Comment: can you post the stack trace from crash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your should just add the super call in onPause() which is probably deleted in your code.
First row of the stack trace:
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.user.icecres/com.example.user.icecres.AddCourse} did not call through to super.onPause()

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I added this: 
`public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPause(savedInstanceState);`
And it errors "onPause() in FragmentActivity cannot be applied to (android.os.Bundle)"

Comment: @Win onPause should look like this:

"@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }"

Comment: Adding the `onPause()` and `onResume()`, the app no longer crashes. Though now I'm faced with another problem.

Comment: Problems never cease my friend :D
Good luck and post anything you would like help with.

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured out how to do all of this, next task: doing the same thing for buttons!

Feel free to add/edit anything appropriate to this answer.

This is my final source code:

```
package com.example.user.icecres;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

public class AddCourse extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edCourse1, edCourse2, edCourse3,edCourse4;
    private Button btConfirm, btReset, btBk;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course);

       if(state != null){
           //restore state onStop()
           SharedPreferences pText = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
           String edC1 = pText.getString("edC1", "");
           String edC2 = pText.getString("edC2", "");
           String edC3 = pText.getString("edC3", "");
           String edC4 = pText.getString("edC4", "");

           edCourse1.setText(edC1);
           edCourse2.setText(edC2);
           edCourse3.setText(edC3);
           edCourse4.setText(edC4);


        } else {

            btConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);
            btReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btReset);

            edCourse1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCourse1);
            edCourse2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCourse2);
            edCourse3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCourse3);
            edCourse4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCourse4);

            btBk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btBk);
        }

        btConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // add course to database
                edCourse1.setText("");
                edCourse2.setText("");
                edCourse3.setText("");
                edCourse4.setText("");
                AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AddCourse.this);
                d.setTitle("Success");
                d.setMessage("Courses have been added");
                d.setPositiveButton("OK", null);


            }

        });
        btReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder c = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AddCourse.this);
                c.setTitle("Confirmation");
                c.setMessage("Would you like to clear all fields?");
                c.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        edCourse1.setText("");
                        edCourse2.setText("");
                        edCourse3.setText("");
                        edCourse4.setText("");
                    }
                });
                c.setNegativeButton("NO",null);
                c.show();
            }

        });
        btBk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent New = new Intent(AddCourse.this, MainPage.class);
                startActivity(New);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences pText = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pText.edit();
        edit.putString("edC1",edCourse1.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC2",edCourse2.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC3",edCourse3.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC4",edCourse4.getText()+"");

        edit.commit();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences pText = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pText.edit();
        edit.putString("edC1",edCourse1.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC2",edCourse2.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC3",edCourse3.getText()+"");
        edit.putString("edC4",edCourse4.getText()+"");

        edit.commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences pText = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        String edC1 = pText.getString("edC1", "");
        String edC2 = pText.getString("edC2", "");
        String edC3 = pText.getString("edC3", "");
        String edC4 = pText.getString("edC4", "");

        edCourse1.setText(edC1);
        edCourse2.setText(edC2);
        edCourse3.setText(edC3);
        edCourse4.setText(edC4);

    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
        //Save instance state
        state.putString("edC1", edCourse1.getText()+"");
        state.putString("edC2", edCourse2.getText()+"");
        state.putString("edC3", edCourse3.getText()+"");
        state.putString("edC4", edCourse4.getText()+"");


    }
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        //Restore instance state on crash
        String edC1 = state.getString("edC1","");
        String edC2 = state.getString("edC2","");
        String edC3 = state.getString("edC3","");
        String edC4 = state.getString("edC4","");
        edCourse2.setText(edC2+"");
        edCourse3.setText(edC3+"");
        edCourse1.setText(edC1+"");
        edCourse4.setText(edC4+"");
    }
}
```

So the `onPause()` and `onStop()` are used to save the text inside the `EditText` fields to the file initialized at the top. The `onResume()` is used to call the texts saved and apply them to the relevant `EditText` fields. The `onSaveInstanceState()` is used to save the state and `onRestoreInstanceState()` is used to restore the state on crash. The `if` `else` in the `onCreate()`, is used to determine if there was a previous state to be restored or not (by `onStop`), and the values are called/initialised depending on this condition.

Hope this helps someone with similar problems!